# ImageButton in toolbar not responding to Click event

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-toolbar, buttonclick, android-imagebutton

I want to put an ImageButton in the toolbar, its a logo, and configure it so that fi the user clicks on it, it takes them to a website.

I am able to show the logo correctly on all 3 fragments, but nothing happens if I click on the logo.

The xml from activity_main looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/jclogo"
            android:onClick="GoToLogo"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Then in the OnActivityCreated in fragment I set up the OnClickListener:

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myLogo = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.logo);
    myLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://somewebsite.co.uk");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I have also implemented and OnClick method:

```
    public void GoToLogo(View v) {
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://somewebsite.co.uk"); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

But nothing happens. There is no recognition of any logo being clicked. Is it not responding because it is in a toolbar?

Thank very much.

Comment: the layout xml file that you post is from framgments or activity?

Comment: @Bruno, it is the xml of the Activity

Comment: So make onclickListener inside activity oncreate method. Not fragment OnActivityCreated method.

Comment: @Bruno, I tried that and it didn't respond to any clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your

```
android:onClick="GoToLogo"
```

and GoToLogo method, you don't need to double the way you define your onClick behavior.

Then try to findView corresponding, it makes more sense to do this in your Activity instead of your fragment..

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `onClick` method `GoToLogo` in your `Activity`, not in `Fragment`.

Comment: thanks. I tried that too and it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should not set the onClickListener again inside the GoToLogo method. Remove that listener and just write what to do after clicking the button.

Comment: yes, tried that and the click on the image is not even registered.

Comment: Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to the `ImageButton`.

Comment: tried and it still does not recognise the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the `onClickListener` in `onCreate()` for now and change the `GoToLogo()` method to this and see if that works

```
public void GoToLogo(View v) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://somewebsite.co.uk"); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: thank you. It just does not even register the click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private ImageButton button;
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view = getView();
    button  = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code stuff   
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What if  `ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.back);`  may help to retrieve the view .